# Exporting multiple datatables into pdf's

Tags: jquery, datatables

We are currently trying to update an already created software, so most of my work is somewhat new. I'm using jQuery to dynamically create tables based on the information a `$.post` returns to the front end. After that, I'm using the DataTables library to convert each table in a DataTable. The initialization of each DataTable, adds the flexibility to export tables into PDF and be printable. My problem is that I need to add a button that adds the feature to have all of those tables and print it in one PDF. I've seen methods to merge the data on the tables, and to download multiple pdfs for each table, but neither of these things does what I want. This is the function I use to create the tables.

```
function createDataTable(table1){
  title = table1[0].dataset.title
  
            table = $(table1).DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50],
                autoWidth: false,
                retrieve: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                // //fixed cols
                // fixedColumns:   {
                //     leftColumns: 1,
                // },
                // scrollY:        "600px",
                // scrollX:        true,
                // scrollCollapse: true,

                bSortCellsTop: true, // To apply sort using top row only
                order: [[ 0, "asc" ]],
                dom: 'Bflrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'collection',
                        text: 'Export <span class="caret"></span>',
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                extend: 'print',
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: ':visible'
                                },
                                text: 'Print',
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                exportOptions: {
                                    columns: ':visible'
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                exportOptions: {
                                  
                                    columns: ':visible',
                                    stripNewlines: false,
                                    title: title,
                                    text: title,
                                    
                                },
                                customize: function(doc){
                                    //$('#loadingModal').modal('show');

                                    doc.pageSize = 'LEGAL';
                                    doc.pageOrientation ='landscape';
                                    doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 10;
                                    doc.styles.tableHeader.fillColor = '#E70033';

                                    // doc.content[1].layout= 'lightHorizontalLines';
                                    doc.content[1].layout = {
                                        hLineWidth: function (i, node) {
                                            if(i === 1){
                                                return 2;
                                            }
                                            else if(i > 1){
                                                return 1;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                return 0;
                                            }
                                        },
                                        vLineWidth: function (i, node) {
                                            return 0;
                                        },
                                        hLineColor: function (i, node) {
                                            if(i === 1){
                                                return '#000';
                                            }
                                            else if(i > 1){
                                                return '#ccc';
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                return 'transparent';
                                            }
                                        },
                                        // vLineColor: function (i, node) {
                                        //     return (i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length) ? 'black' : 'gray';
                                        // },
                                        paddingLeft: function(i, node) { return 5; },
                                        paddingRight: function(i, node) { return 5; },
                                        paddingTop: function(i, node) { return 5; },
                                        paddingBottom: function(i, node) { return 5; }
                                    };

                                    doc.content.splice( 0, 0, {
                                        margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 12 ],
                                        alignment: 'center',
                                        width: 150
                                    } );

                                    //$('#loadingModal').modal('hide');

                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'colvis',
                        columns: ':gt(0)',
                        text: 'Column visibility <span class="caret"></span>',
                    }
                ],
            });
            // tables.push(table);

            // Apply the search
            table.columns().every( function ()
            {
                // Search by keyword
                var column = this;
                $('input.column-search-bar', column.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (column.search() !== this.value) {
                        console.log(this.value)

                        column
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );

                // Search by dropdown menu
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function (d, j) {
                    $('select.column-search-select', column.footer()).append('<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>');
                });

                $('.column-search-select', column.footer()).on( 'change', function () {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());

                column
                    .search(val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false)
                    .draw();

                } );
            } );

            table.buttons().container()
            .appendTo( $('.col-sm-6:eq(0)', table.table().container()));

            $(document).on('click', '.buttons-columnVisibility', function(){
                console.log('visibility toggled');
                table.columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
            });
        return table;
}
```

I need to clarify once again, this is a chunk of code that was already written years ago and it is not exactly mine. I thought of adding a button that calls a function, that adds each table into a pdf before downloading, but I haven't found a solution.

As an added bonus, I have a problem changing the title, I'm trying to print the tables with a specific title on top of the tables but I have not figured out how to yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt the dataTable plugin will be of use except for extracting the data or the rows html that it stores in cache. You most likely need to aggregate everything needed yourself and use a js pdf library to generate the result once you have it all aggregated. If it was me I would start with a set of really simple html tables (no dataTable plugin) and use those to get the basics working. Then apply to the more advanced plugin versions. Aggregating the multiple tables should be a fairly easy task

Comment: I will try to do this and try to replicate the pdf document it already created. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. If you run into issues on more specific sub task of this ask another question